# Show loading animation (div element), during code behind execution (c# and asp net)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using the following loading animation within my code. I want it to be visible during a Excel SQL import, that I created. The Excel import is done using c# and the code behind. The following button is triggering the import script:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Always">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="savebutton" ClientIDMode="Static" class="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" Visible="True" OnClick="Savebutton_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my loading animation:

```
<!-- Loading Element -->
<div runat="server" visible="false" id ="loading" class="loader"></div>
```

My problem is that every time I start the import and at the beginning I use `"loading.Visible = true;"`  the element is not visible until the import/the code execution is finished.

I need it to be shown right from the beginning. And  I want it to be hidden after the loading process is finished. I tried multiple ways showing the animation throught javascript and C# but nothing worked so far.

I hope you can help me..

Thank you very much

Kind regards

Shazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first putting `visible="false"` will result in completely not rendering the control. So you don't have the div available on the clientside so you cannot show it then.

As second you can use a [UpdateProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx) control for this.

But to answer your question. You have to handle the button click clientside. So instead of straight triggering server side event first show your div.

add  `OnClientClick="showDiv()"` to handle clientside before triggering the button

```
<asp:Button ID="savebutton" class="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="showDiv()" OnClick="Savebutton_Click" />

//the js to remove imHidden from className
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('<%=loading.ClientID%>').className = "loader";
}
```

Add a class to hide the div instead of using visible so the div will render to client but won't show

```
<div id ="loading" runat="server" class="loader imHidden"></div>
```

css

```
.imHidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Also set your load div inside the updatepanel so it will update itself back to the original hidden

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, but it is not possible to bind the exection to the button, because there are several if statements, that could prevent the upload from happening, so a loading animation makes no sense at this point. But when I try to do something like this: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "value", "show_loader();", true); The loading animation still starts after the entire script has run. It seems like the C# does not allow the javscript function to run until it is finished..

Comment: @Shazy i don't see a issue. The loading animation will just be shorter and you will give feedback to the user that something is happening. Hope you can tweak the given example to your needs

Comment: @Shazy `RegisterStartUpScript` does exactly what the name says. You are working disconnected. Meaning the script gets triggered when it arrives to the client from the server. And the only moment it goes back to client is after it executed all code on the server. Resulting in the behavior you have now.